# if then else statement issues

Tags: bash, shell-script

I'm attempting to write a script that checks for certain data within existing files. example:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -x
if [ 'grep PASS_WARN_AGE /etc/login.defs' == 'PASS_WARN_AGE    7' ]; then
        echo "RHEL-06-000054 not a finding"

elif [ 'grep PASS_WARN_AGE /etc/login.defs' == 'PASS_WARN_AGE    0' ]; then
        sed -ie 's/PASS_WARN_AGE\s\s\s\s0/PASS_WARN_AGE    7/g' /etc/login.defs

else echo "Needs further review"
fi
```

This script ignored the if and elif strings, and only echos the "Needs further review" string.  Essentially, I want this script to tell me if the current value is set to 7.  If the value is 0 and not 7, then it executes a sed command, changing the value within the file /etc/login.defs.  If some unknown output is presented, it tells the user that further review is necessary.  All help is appreciated.

Comment: `'grep blah'` isn't a command, it's just a quoted string, so is not run at all. Also you'll probably need the `-o` option to `grep` to only get the matching bit...

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out.

```
    #!/bin/bash
set -x
grep -q 'PASS_WARN_AGE    7' /etc/login.defs
if [ ${?} -eq 0 ]; then
        echo "RHEL-06-000054 not a finding"

grep -q 'PASS_WARN_AGE    0' /etc/login.defs
elif [ ${?} -eq 0 ]; then
        sed -ie 's/PASS_WARN_AGE\s\s\s\s0/PASS_WARN_AGE    7/g' /etc/login.defs; echo "RHEL-06-000054 patched"

else echo "needs further review"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just unconditionally run `sed` on the file if you like:

```
sed -i .bak -Ee 's/^PASS_WARN_AGE\s+0/PASS_WARN_AGE    7/' /etc/login.defs
```

I would be wary of using a pattern like `\s\s\s\s` since the amount of white space might vary. I don't think `\s` is standard, but I suppose if the context is RHEL, you'll have GNU sed anyway.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use backticks (`) to let the commands work, in the code you provide in your question you compare two static strings. ` != '